# Photon Stand Alone Server Unity3D .Net5 issue

Tags: entity-framework, server, .net-5, photon

I am trying to start a Photon Server that I have been building. I have heard that Photon Server and Unity3D don't directly support .net5 but there has to be a work around to make this work. This is the first attempt to create a Photon Server. When starting my .net5 stand alone server I get this error in my project log:

29244: 18:45:31.948 - CService::OnException() - Exception: CManagedHost::StartApplication() - Failed to start application in AppDomain: 2 - The system cannot find the file specified.

I wish the log would tell me what file they can't find.

In my PhotonCLR.Log I notice that my ConfigurationFile and CachePath = ', which in the tutorial I am watching mentions this being a issue for Photon. [Tutorial Series](https://youtu.be/OdJ4YVFweAo) Thanks Christian Richards.

INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - CreateAppDomain: name = 'TestServer' , assemblyName = 'PhotonServer'
INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - ApplicationBase = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy'
INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - PrivateBinPath = 'bin_Win64;Shared;C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy\TestServer\bin;'

INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - ConfigurationFile = ''

INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - CachePath = ''

INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - ApplicationPath = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy\TestServer'
INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - BinaryPath = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy\TestServer\bin'
INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - ApplicationRootPath = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy'
INFO PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager - UnmanagedLogPath = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Photon Server SDK\deploy\bin_Win64\log'

With PhotonDomainManager is there away to set the cache path and configuration file? Also what file is it expecting it you can set it?

If I can set it will that be a good workaround or is there another option to Photon Server to run? If not I will have to figure out how to migrate back my projects to .Net Framework 4.6.2 or .Net Standard? I would rather not do this because some of the projects are shared with my WebApi. One of the 2 projects that is shared is Entity Framework, which would be difficult moving to .net standard and the other is a core project that I want to be used by WebApi, Blazor, Photon, and Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on Photon forum [here](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/56651/#Comment_56651):

> we did not test with .net 5. it is officially not supported yet
> use .netframework 4.x

Comment: I understand but that means I have to push back so many projects back to .Net Standard 2.0. So I have to use Entity Framework 2.2.0 which is 3 years old. I lose a lot of the basic functionality that I want my software to do. I know Unity3D is targeting .net6 release around the same time that it hits in a 3 months. How long afterwards can I expect PhotonServer to be able to support it? I know .net 6 will be the .net standard nationwide.